# Count Dom element by class name in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom, classname

I need help getting element count by class name and data-date:

```
<td data-date="2017-11-10">
    <div class="animal">Mouse</div>
    <div class="animal">Dog</div>
</td>
<td data-date="2017-11-11">
    <div class="animal">Bird</div>
</td>
<td data-date="2017-11-12">
    <div class="animal">Cat</div>
    <div class="animal">Horse</div>
    <div class="animal">Snake</div>
    <div class="animal">Tiger</div>
</td>
```

Output

```
2017-11-10: 2
2017-11-11: 1
2017-11-12: 4
```

Thank you.

Comment: Will there ever be more than one element with the same `data-date` value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Loop each tr td.
2. Use `.attr()` to get the attribute
3. use `.length` to get the number of element with class

```js
$('table tr td[data-date]').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);



  console.log($this.attr('data-date') + " : " +
    $this.find('.animal').length)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>Not included td</td>
    <td data-date="2017-11-10">
      <div class="animal">Mouse</div>
      <div class="animal">Dog</div>
    </td>
    <td data-date="2017-11-11">
      <div class="animal">Bird</div>
    </td>
    <td data-date="2017-11-12">
      <div class="animal">Cat</div>
      <div class="animal">Horse</div>
      <div class="animal">Snake</div>
      <div class="animal">Tiger</div>
    </td>
     <td>Not included td</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Might be nicer to use a selector like `$('[data-date]')` instead of `$('td')`, so that only relevant TD elements will be selected and not all TDs on the page. (Obviously the OP didn't show any other TDs, but a real page could have other tables.)

Comment: Thank you all for super quick response! Appreciate it.

Comment: @ombinar glad to help mate happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var collection = {};
$('td').each(function(){
  collection[$(this).data('date')] = $(this).children('div.animal').length;
});

console.log(collection);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-date="2017-11-10">
      <div class="animal">Mouse</div>
      <div class="animal">Dog</div>
    </td>
    <td data-date="2017-11-11">
      <div class="animal">Bird</div>
    </td>
    <td data-date="2017-11-12">
      <div class="animal">Cat</div>
      <div class="animal">Horse</div>
      <div class="animal">Snake</div>
      <div class="animal">Tiger</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Loop over and use data and find

```js
var counts = {}
$("td").each( function (i, td) {
   var $td = $(td) 
   counts[$td.data("date")] = $td.find("div").length
})
console.log(counts);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-date="2017-11-10">
      <div class="animal">Mouse</div>
      <div class="animal">Dog</div>
    </td>
    <td data-date="2017-11-11">
      <div class="animal">Bird</div>
    </td>
    <td data-date="2017-11-12">
      <div class="animal">Cat</div>
      <div class="animal">Horse</div>
      <div class="animal">Snake</div>
      <div class="animal">Tiger</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
$("td").each(function() {
  console.log( $(this).prop('data-date') + ": " + $(this).children().length );
});
```